# sound effect for jQuery UI Easing plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Easing plugin and would like to have corresponding sound effect when animation happens. How can I possibly do that ?
Here is its HTML and script

[image]
<sub>(source: [placehold.it](https://placehold.it/250x70))</sub>

```
    $('img').click(function() {
    $('img')
        .animate({left: '400px', top: '400px'}, 3000, "easeInOutQuad")
        .animate({left: '-=400px', top: '-=400px', opacity: 0}, 3000, "easeInCubic");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using html5 audio.

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
$('img').click(function() {
    audio.play();  
    $('img')
    .animate({left: '400px', top: '400px'}, 3000, "easeInOutQuad")
    .animate({left: '-=400px', top: '-=400px', opacity: 0}, 3000, "easeInCubic");
});
```

Comment: how can I control play() function let's say make it play non-stop or pause it after some milliseconds ?

Comment: You can find more on the javascript media object here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp. You could do something  like `setTimeout(function(){audio.pause(); audio.currentTime = 0;}, 500)`; For autoplay, you could probably bind to the `ended` callback, and do `audio.play()` there. Never done it, but it should work.